# C# Is it possible to wire up an event to a method when it is finished?

Tags: c#

I have a .dll file and in there, there's a method called A. When I call that method I'd like to call a method of my own,  method B. So my question is, is it possible to call method B immediately when method A is finished?

Offcourse I can call method A and after that call method B manually. But I was wondering is there a manner to do this automatically, maybe with an event? So when method A is finished the event gets fired somehow and method A is called.

Edit:
I don't have control over the .dll. So I cannot change anything in method A.

Comment: You could also have a look at the Rx extensions. It's an uber-cool new way of responding to events that treat events as normal IEnumerable collections...

Have a look at this article http://haacked.com/archive/2010/03/26/enumerating-future.aspx

Comment: AOP, like Postsharp.  Link: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp

Comment: @Martijn: is A called asynchronously?

Comment: why not just subclass the A's class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have control over the dll, write a wrapper class

```
public class WrapAnotherClass : AnotherClass
{
    public EventHandler DoSomethingFinished;

    public new void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();

        var temp = DoSomethingFinished;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), specifically [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net/msil-injection:

> MSIL Injection, or MSIL Insertion, is
>   the process of modifying the MSIL
>   instructions of an existing method.
>   One says that we inject, or insert 
>   new instructions into an existing
>   flow.

Comment: this would work, but the OP indicates he cannot change Method A

Answer (score 1):

If you control the class where method A is defined then I would go with the event approach. Here is a short example following MSDN [Event Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Did;

    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do");

        this.OnDid(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected void OnDid(EventArgs e)
    {
        var evt = this.Did;

        if (evt != null)
        {
            evt(this, e);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.Did += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Did");

        foo.Do();
    }
}
```

If you want to run method `B` for every instance of the class that defines `A` you can create a helper method to create the instance and immediately add an event handler.

```
public static Foo CreateFoo()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    foo.Did += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Did");

    return foo;
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over method A (Do in your example).

Answer (score 1):

Only with either cooperation of the target method (it calls a delegate or fires an event) or of the caller (replace the call to A with an intermediate method that calls you method).

You could also re-write the IL to modify `A` to allow such a callback (or in theory use debugger APIs), but that is much more complex.

The wrapper approach would be something like:

```
var AWrapped = () => { A(); MyHelper(); };
```

and replace all calls to `A`, with `AWrapped`, or more explicitly:

Original caller code:

```
//...
A();
//...
```

and replace with:

```
//...
AWrapped();
//...
```

(If this is to be used in more than a couple of places, or in more than one type, then I would use a static function (possibly an extension function) to do the wrapping.)

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @Martijn: I've tried to expand it, but in the end a wrapper is pretty simple. If you control neither the implementation of `A` or its callers then you only have hard options.

Answer (score 0):

If method A allows dependency injection it can be possible by injecting your own dependency. How? Probably someone else good at it can tell you that if at all your method A allows dependency. I'm not good at it.

Secondly you can extend class (if it is not sealed) which contains method A and override the functionality of method A to wire up an event. Now use the instance of extended class everywhere to call method A

Answer (score 0):

Seen as you dont have access to the code you'll have to create a wrapper to encapsulate it.

Like so:

```
class Wrapper
{
   private A = new A(); //this is your closed .dll class

   public event EventHandler DoneThing;

   private void OnDoneThing()
   {
      if(DoneThing!=null)
      {
        DoneThing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
      }
   }

   public void DoThing()
   {
       A.DoThing();
       OnDoneThing();
   }
}
```